# Page submenu is not shown for custom user role on Wordpress admin page (WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I retitled and moved the WooCommerce Products top-level menu to underneath the main WooCommerce tab with the following code:

```
 $products = recursive_array_search_php_91365( 'Products', $menu );
 unset ($menu[$products]);
 add_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'Donation Options', 'Donation Options', 'manage_options, products', '/edit.php?post_type=product');
```

The recursive array search function is pulled from [this page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100758/renaming-a-wordpress-admin-menu).

My custom user roles are created and managed through the User Role Editor plugin.  The desired menu shows up for an administrator, but not for my custom user role.  I checked and this user can access the page that is called back, so I'm not sure why it isn't be displayed in the menu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$capability` of the `add_submenu_page` function you are passing **`manage_options`**. *So only a super admin or an administrator can view it.* See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) for more information.

So to have it also displayed to users with the custom role **you will need to replace** `manage_options` **with the capability of your custom user role**.

Here is a complete list:

- [Roles and Capabilities](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/)

There is a syntax error in the capability field, it should look like this:

```
add_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'Donation Options', 'Donation Options', 'manage_options', 'products', '/edit.php?post_type=product' );
```

Also you have to replace `/edit.php?post_type=product` with the name of a callback function otherwise you will get the following warning:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '/edit.php?post_type=product' not found or invalid function name
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I just copied and pasted the add_submenu_page function and didn't understand what the "manage_options" parameter did.  I changed it to "editor" and now it works great.